# Completing the square - cannot solve versus standard Quadratic Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the equation $a^2 - 2ax -1 = 0$, I have tried to calculate the value of $a$ by completing the square and it is not working out compared to the normal quadratic formula $-b^2$.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Ed.

Comment: What is the variable you want to solve for? $a$?

Comment: **Hint** $a^2 - 2 a x = (a - x)^2 - x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

We have the [completing the square method](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/algebra/quadequationshirev2.shtml), which says $$x^2+ax+b=0 \implies \left(x+\frac a2\right)^2-\left(\frac a2\right)^2+b=0$$

In your question, we have $x=a$, $a=-2x$, and $b=-1$, so we can say:

\begin{align}a^2-2ax-1&=0\\
\left(a+\frac{-2x}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{-2x}{2}\right)^2-1&=0\\
(a-x)^2-x^2-1&=0\\
(a-x)^2&=1+x^2\\
a-x&=\pm\sqrt{1+x^2}\\
a&=x\pm\sqrt{1+x^2}\end{align}

---

We could also use the [quadratic formula](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/algebra/quadequationshirev3.shtml):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\implies x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

In your question, we have $x=a$, $a=1$, $b=-2x$, and $c=-1$, so we can say:

\begin{align}a&=\frac{-(-2x)\pm\sqrt{(-2x)^2-4\times 1\times -1}}{2\times 1}\\
&=\frac{2x\pm\sqrt{4x^2+4}}{2}\\
&=\frac{2x\pm\sqrt{4(x^2+1)}}{2}\\
&=\frac{2x\pm\sqrt{4}\times\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}\\
&=\frac{2x\pm 2\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}\\
&=x\pm\sqrt{x^2+1}\end{align}